# How to move data from kafka broker simultaneously with reading/writing

Tags: apache-kafka

I have now 4 nodes of kafka in cluster.
kafka1 is old and has all data and it's controller
kafka2,3,4 is new and without data

Data is writing and reading continiously to/from kafka1

Can i do this:

1. Change dns kafka1 to kafka4 (this is cluster - will  data write
   right?)
2. start kafka-reassign-partitions.sh for move data from kafka1
   to kafka4 s
3. shutdown kafka1
4. Add replicas to topics

Is this right? Or is better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like that while you have several brokers now, all your partitions are still only on the old broker.

The best way to spread the usage is to use the reassignment script `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` as you hinted. This will allow you to move some of the topics on the new brokers.

At the same time, you can add replicas for the topics. Having multiple replicas provide guarantees, for example in case a broker goes down, you'll still have online replicas.

Comment: Hello and thank you for your answer! First of all, i'm afraid inconsistency, so many brokers now writing to old broker and many consumers reading from it. What will happen to them and data  while the script is running?

Comment: While reassigning topics they should all stay available. Once a new broker takes over, clients should automatically detect it and connect to the new leader.

I suggest you look at:
- http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#basic_ops_cluster_expansion
- http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#rep-throttle
These 2 sections detail how to do such a migration

Comment: all is good except Topic: __consumer_offsets
it is strange

# of Partitions 50

Preferred Replicas 0%

Under Replicated Partitions 0

Total Size -50

Total Available Messages 0